# How to show opera in the dash?

Tags: unity-dash, opera

Well, I've changed the default browser to `opera` in the Preferred Applications:

[image]

`firefox`  is still in the dash.
Before this `Chromium` was the default browser, and it was in the dash after making it the default browser.

For example: I've changed The default music player to `Clementine` and it didn't take time to show in the dash :[image]

But the problem is still that Opera isn't showing in the dash, I think that there is something preventing `opera` from showing in the dash.

Comment: Did you reboot or restart unity after that? That's when it worked after switching to thunderbird for me.

Comment: @K.Hendrik Yes,I did a restart.Should I do again ?

Comment: @Rinzwind it is still the same, Opera is not showing, although I use opera like-everyday.

Comment: Is there a way to tell Opera it's the default browser from it's preferences?

Comment: I found a bug claiming it is hardcoded: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/708479

Comment: Guys, you need to start putting your information in your questions and answers, it's impossible to keep track of things in comments, please stop misusing them and just update your question!

Comment: [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/775422) and as such is now closed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Uninstalling the browsers I didn't want to see in the Dash and then reinstalling them solved it. Try removing Firefox and Chromium; Opera should appear in the Dash and stay there even after you reinstall them.

Comment: I tried to do  this , But it didn't work for me. Thanks BTW

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Rinzwind bug report does this gconf-editor value match?

[image]

Comment: The value is `/usr/bin/opera`